# How Wikipedia manage links in database?

Tags: database, wikipedia

I have searched a lot of websites but could not find the answer of this question.

When we search an article, this article contains many highlighted words. When I click on these words another web page opens. I want to understand that how database of Wikipedia manages all these things or in other words how different web pages are interlinked from database point of view.

Comment: This question is **too broad**, son.

Comment: I don't think this question is too broad. It is a specific problem and one that I would argue everybody should know how to solve. But this question does suggest that there is a lack of understanding of how Databases work. @Naeem, what have you tried? How do _you_ think this can be done?

Comment: sir i am working on a project and i want to know this thing.plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia runs on [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki), and there are a few ways it stores [links](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Link#Wikilinks):

- Each page is saved in the [text table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Text_table) as wikitext, which can include [wikitext links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Wiki_markup#Free_links) (like `[[this]]`) that MediaWiki will [parse](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parser.php) and render as [html hyperlinks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).
- Links are also added to the [pagelinks table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pagelinks_table) for easy access via the [MediaWiki API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&titles=Coffee) and other [handy features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/Computer_Online_Forensic_Evidence_Extractor).
- Links to external websites (i.e. pages outside of Wikipedia) are added to the [externallinks table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Externallinks_table), and categories are added to the [categorylinks table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Categorylinks_table).